# cmake compiling but not linking a new source file in a library (libonion)

Tags: linux, cmake

I am a `cmake` newbie (on Debian/Sid/Linux/x86-64)

I forked libonion on https://github.com/bstarynk/onion to enable customization of `malloc` with Boehm's garbage collector; see [this mail thread](https://groups.google.com/a/coralbits.com/d/msg/onion-dev/XxhtpYUBozw/oZ-TqS0VNDMJ).

I added two files there `onion/src/low_util.c` and `onion_src/low_util.h` (which is `#include`-d successfully in several other patched files.

It is compiled but not linked.

```
 set(SOURCES onion.c codecs.c dict.c low_util.c request.c response.c handler.c 
                    log.c sessions.c sessions_mem.c shortcuts.c block.c mime.c url.c ${POLLER_C}
        listen_point.c request_parser.c http.c ${HTTPS_C} websocket.c ${RANDOM_C} ${SQLITE3_C})
```

later:

```
 SET(INCLUDES_ONION block.h codecs.h dict.h handler.h http.h https.h listen_point.h low_util.h log.h mime.h onion.h poller.h request.h response.h server.h sessions.h shortcuts.h types.h types_internal.h url.h websocket.h ${SQLITE3_H})
 MESSAGE(STATUS "Found include files ${INCLUDES_ONION}")
```

but when I [build](https://groups.google.com/a/coralbits.com/d/msg/onion-dev/XxhtpYUBozw/QZqEqWdCwwoJ), my file `low_util.c` got compiled but not linked.

```
Linking C executable otemplate
CMakeFiles/opack.dir/__/__/src/onion/dict.c.o: In function `onion_dict_new':
dict.c:(.text+0x1bc): undefined reference to `onionlow_calloc'
CMakeFiles/opack.dir/__/__/src/onion/dict.c.o: In function `onion_dict_node_data_free':
dict.c:(.text+0x2ec): undefined reference to `onionlow_free'
CMakeFiles/opack.dir/__/__/src/onion/dict.c.o: In function `onion_dict_node_add':
```

Notice that `libonion` is a library (in C, providing HTTP service) and that I just want to add a `low_util.c` file (wrapping `malloc` & `pthread_create` etc... to make Boehm's GC happy: it is calling `GC_malloc` and `GC_pthread_create` ....) with its `low_util.h` header. Surprisingly, they get compiled, but do not seems to be linked. And *I am not familiar with `cmake`* and I am not familiar with how D.Moreno (the main author of `libonion`) has organized his *cmake* files.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the following patch to make it link. The two executables which are being linked with the symbols generated from the .c file you added are missing and are added in the patch.

http://pastebin.com/mDMRiUQu

Comment: Thanks, David Moreno suggested an equivalent patch, and now things are better!

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you posted, its hard to tell what could be wrong. The cake source code above says that a variable `${SOURCES}` is equivalent to `onion.c codecs.c dict.c low_util.c ... ${SQLITE3_C}`, and a variable `${INCLUDE_ONION}` is equivalent to `block.h codecs.h dict.h ... ${SQLITE3_H}`. You did not provide any targets or the files included in those targets.

A brief list of things that may help:

- where do you define the top level library or executable?  If your making a library, you will need the command [add_library()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aadd_library).  If you are making an executable, you will need the `add_executable()` command.
- Use the command [target_link_libraries()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries) to resolve dependencies.  Rather than placing all of the source files in a single library, group similar together in a single target (a target is defined by the add_* commands), and use this command to link the targets after compilation.
- Use the find_package() to get any libraries which are defined on your system but not in you project. Then, link to that library using the `target_link_libraries()` command.

In this case, if the `onion_dict_*` functions are defined within the same library, your not including those files in library.  When you use add_library or add_executable, ensure you add those files to the list.  If the functions are within your project but not in the same library, use the `target_link_libraries()` command to link to the library which contains the correct files. If those commands are defined in an external library, then first find the library using `find_package()`, and then link to the library using `target_link_libraries()`.

Comment: *I* don't use `cmake`. D.Moreno (the author of `libonion`) uses it. I just want to patch his library and test my patches....

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you would like to do. If you are adding additional files in the onion/src directory, you will need to patch the onion/src/CMakeLists.txt file by adding your own library (using add_library()) that contains your source files, and use target_link_libraries() to link the new library to the pre-packages libraries. If you are just patching the source files, you shouldn't need to touch the CMake files.